# Convert strings within an array to list in Python

Tags: python, string, list, numpy

I want to convert the array `A` containing string elements to list. But I am running into error while using `split()`. I present the expected output.

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import nan
A=np.array(['[1]', '[2]',  '[3]', '[4]', '[5]'])
A.split()
print(A)
```

The error is

```
in <module>
    A.split()

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'
```

The expected output is

```
array([[1], [2], [3], [4], [5]])
```

Comment: Try this: `A = np.array([eval(e) for e in A])`

Comment: A string has a `split` method, not a list!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should work

```py
A=np.array(['[1]', '[2]',  '[3]', '[4]', '[5]'])
output = [[int(a.strip("[|]"))] for a in A]
print(output)
```

```
[[1], [2], [3], [4], [5]]
```

if you prefer just an list, instead of a list of list

```py
A=np.array(['[1]', '[2]',  '[3]', '[4]', '[5]'])
output = [int(a.strip("[|]")) for a in A]
print(output)
```

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: The output I am getting with your code is ```[array(['[1]', '[2]', '[3]', '[4]', '[5]'], dtype='<U3')]```.

Comment: I have edited the the code if you print output is impossible you are getting this. Things apart I don't get why you are using numpy to have an array of strings.

Comment: I think you are printing A and not output. A is the array you have as input, output is what you want

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array(['[1]', '[2]',  '[3]', '[4]', '[5]'])
B = np.array([int(item.strip("'\'").replace("[","").replace("]","")) for item in A] )
print(B) #[1 2 3 4 5]
```